# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException exception in using UPS web service

Tags: .net, exception, ups

I am using a web service from https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate to incorporate UPS shipping calculations in my asp.net project. While running the project, I got an exception  as below:

> Description: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP
> Header SOAPAction: http://localhost:4594/ShippingModule.asmx/GetUPSShippingCost. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
> Source: System.Web.Services

I am running it now in localhost. Is that the source of this exception? Or the customed namespace used in the web service is the main issue?
I searched a lot on web for this problem. But didn't get any wayout to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

@user286035,

The exception itself is clear,**Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction**

That means the soap envelope you are sending has a header which has element SOAPAction whose value is not recognized by the server. If SOAPAction elemnt is required then try to put proper value in it & then post it to the SOAP service.

Use TCPMonitor to monitor the request that is being sent to server, it will provide you a clear idea.